# Reverse DNS to get hostname of private IPs

Tags: dns

I want to put a filter to ignore the unnecessary requests from the various systems in my local network. Since IP keeps changing, so I want to put filter on hostnames. But from the request I can only get IP not hostname. So, how I can resolve this or how can I use reverse DNS on my private network?

Comment: More than one hostname can point to the same IP, so such a lookup would not necessarily be unique. What sort of answer are you expecting to get form this reverse lookup?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. Reverse DNS returns the hostname if you query an ip address. Because ip addresses change, this will not help you?